# Why retinanet model model.predict() return only boxes with -1 after training?

Tags: object-detection, predict, keras-cv

I have been studying keras-cv repository and I have some questions that I was hoping you could help me with. I am currently working on a ship detection model. So I am trying to implement  retinaNet model. After suiting my data to the specific keras-cv input I tried to fit the model. However I am experiencing some troubles with predictions.

PROBLEM :When I use `model.fit(image_test)` the predictions returned are all -1 :

```
{'boxes': array([[[-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.],
    [-1., -1., -1., -1.]]], dtype=float32), 'confidence': array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32), 'classes': array([[-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,
    -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.]], dtype=float32), 'num_detections': array([0], dtype=int32)}
```

When I try with `model(image_test)` I get :

```
predictions =
{'box': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 49104, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.09781634,  0.19049369, -0.04102969, -0.21385634],
    [-0.2612432 ,  0.17355151, -0.15664971,  0.14730531],
    [-0.19195703,  0.3431507 ,  0.14365467,  0.06342052],
    ...,
    [ 0.00151845,  0.0044898 , -0.01494532,  0.00200025],
    [ 0.01669142, -0.01205819,  0.01728174,  0.00686904],
    [ 0.02757294, -0.00464585, -0.01185186, -0.00704384]]],
  dtype=float32)>, 'classification': <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 49104, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-4.491832 , -4.6013255],
    [-4.2144737, -4.557256 ],
    [-4.6533785, -4.6464787],
    ...,
    [-4.5967946, -4.599116 ],
    [-4.6118917, -4.59214  ],
    [-4.5627737, -4.5775194]]], dtype=float32)>}
```

This is data I used :

```
image_test = 
tf.Tensor(
[[[[0.3839975  0.27996504 0.33198124]
[0.40149528 0.29109997 0.34629762]
[0.44508073 0.27996504 0.36252287]
...
[0.37477133 0.22842602 0.30159864]
[0.3979957  0.25674066 0.32736814]
[0.3760439  0.21379144 0.29491767]]

[[0.39481428 0.29269072 0.34375247]
[0.394178   0.30605265 0.35011533]
[0.40149528 0.30764335 0.35456935]
...
[0.42312893 0.26342162 0.34327528]
[0.43203694 0.25801322 0.34502506]
[0.40181342 0.22365387 0.31273365]]

[[0.41390282 0.30923405 0.36156845]
[0.37699834 0.31591508 0.34645668]
[0.3101885  0.2993717  0.3047801 ]
...
[0.44571704 0.2828283  0.36427265]
[0.4425356  0.25801322 0.35027438]
[0.41485724 0.24178797 0.3283226 ]]
```

...

```
[[0.3585461  0.27837428 0.31846023]
[0.29746282 0.2882367  0.29284978]
[0.29173627 0.28251016 0.2871232 ]
...
[0.29587212 0.29841724 0.29714468]
[0.31336996 0.2993717  0.3063708 ]
[0.36809036 0.30064425 0.3343673 ]]

[[0.36109126 0.29396328 0.32752725]
[0.32768634 0.29841724 0.31305176]
[0.3079615  0.27392033 0.2909409 ]
...
[0.3525014  0.3079615  0.33023146]
[0.34295717 0.30191684 0.322437  ]
[0.37063548 0.3025531  0.3365943 ]]

[[0.35568285 0.30191684 0.32879984]
[0.33182216 0.2936451  0.31273365]
[0.32705003 0.27551103 0.30128053]
...
[0.42853734 0.29269072 0.360614  ]
[0.40213156 0.28537342 0.34375247]
[0.3820886  0.2847371  0.33341286]]]], shape=(1, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32)`
```

my model is trained with images and labels with following pattern :

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[[0.33106965, 0.24011646, 0.285593  ],
     [0.32864422, 0.24666505, 0.2876546 ],
     [0.31190884, 0.24545236, 0.2786806 ],
     ...,
     [0.27674025, 0.22459374, 0.250667  ],
     [0.2527286 , 0.21925785, 0.2359932 ],
     [0.27334464, 0.2211982 , 0.2472714 ]],

    [[0.31215134, 0.25709438, 0.28462285],
     [0.31554696, 0.25782198, 0.28668448],
     [0.30657288, 0.25054574, 0.27855933],
     ...,
     [0.2791657 , 0.22895953, 0.2540626 ],
     [0.2660684 , 0.24423967, 0.25515404],
     [0.29008004, 0.23041478, 0.2602474 ]],

    [[0.30196458, 0.25685182, 0.2794082 ],
     [0.3087558 , 0.2532137 , 0.28098473],
     [0.30705798, 0.24690762, 0.2769828 ],
     ...,
     [0.26364297, 0.21974294, 0.24169298],
     [0.23914629, 0.2226534 , 0.23089983],
     [0.2786806 , 0.22071311, 0.24969682]],

    ...,

    [[0.29759887, 0.21877277, 0.2581858 ],
     [0.30341986, 0.19936942, 0.25139466],
     [0.3060878 , 0.18869756, 0.2473927 ],
     ...,
     [0.21101144, 0.23381034, 0.22241089],
     [0.20227993, 0.2231385 , 0.2127092 ],
     [0.21295173, 0.22507884, 0.21901529]],

    [[0.32670388, 0.22895953, 0.27783167],
     [0.32888675, 0.20422022, 0.2665535 ],
     [0.3233083 , 0.19500364, 0.259156  ],
     ...,
     [0.21683241, 0.23672086, 0.22677661],
     [0.21343681, 0.22071311, 0.21707493],
     [0.21780258, 0.226049  , 0.2219258 ]],

    [[0.30633035, 0.21537717, 0.26085377],
     [0.32112542, 0.21343681, 0.26728114],
     [0.32476354, 0.21295173, 0.26885766],
     ...,
     [0.2231385 , 0.24254183, 0.23284017],
     [0.21489207, 0.23041478, 0.2226534 ],
     [0.20470531, 0.23235507, 0.2185302 ]]]], dtype=float32)>, {'boxes': <tf.RaggedTensor         [[[22.0, 285.0, 4.0, 6.0],
```

[203.0, 301.0, 4.0, 4.0],
[237.0, 146.0, 25.0, 20.0]]]>, 'classes': <tf.RaggedTensor [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0]]>})`

The main CODE :

```
from GPU_manager.gpu_manager import GPU_manager
from Configs.configs import CFG
from Data_factory.data_generator import Data_generator

import os.path
import pandas as pd

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import keras_cv
import datetime
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Workaround to silent tf INFO messages (but not WARNING and ERROR messages)
# Must happen before importing tensorflow
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

# GLOBALS
MODEL = 'retinaNET'
NB_SAMPLES = CFG['Model']["dataset"]["NB_SAMPLES"]
BATCH_SIZE = CFG['Model']["train"]["BATCH_SIZE"]
EPOCHS = CFG['Model']["train"]["EPOCHS"]
SPLIT_PATH = os.path.join(CFG["Resource"]["Dataset"]["Xview_radar"]["ANNOTATIONS_DIR"],         "validation_scaled.csv")
CHIP_DIR = CFG["Resource"]["Dataset"]["Xview_radar"]["CHIP_DIR"]
TIME = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
CHECKPOINT_PATH = os.path.join(CFG["Resource"]["Savings"]["SAVE_DIR"], MODEL, "checkpoint",    "fit" + TIME, "cp.ckpt")
LOGS_DIR = os.path.join(CFG["Resource"]["Savings"]["SAVE_DIR"], MODEL, "logs", "fit" + TIME)

# gpu configuration
gpu = GPU_manager()
gpu.setup_gpu_env()

# Dataset
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
# load the data
patch_paths = Data_generator.parse_data_directory(CHIP_DIR)

train, remain = train_test_split(patch_paths, train_size=0.8, random_state=0, shuffle=True)
valid, test = train_test_split(remain, test_size=0.5, random_state=0, shuffle=True)

train_generator = Data_generator(train, BATCH_SIZE, split='train', shuffle_on_epoch_end=True, shuffle_at_init=True)
#train_dataset = train_generator.data_loader()

valid_generator = Data_generator(valid, BATCH_SIZE, split='valid', shuffle_on_epoch_end=True, shuffle_at_init=True)
#valid_dataset = valid_generator.data_loader()

test_generator = Data_generator(test, batch_size=1, split='test', shuffle_on_epoch_end=True, shuffle_at_init=True)
#test_dataset = test_generator.data_loader()

# Model
print("\nModel")
print(f"-- {MODEL}")
print(f"-- BATCH_SIZE : {BATCH_SIZE}")
print(f"-- EPOCHS : {EPOCHS}")

model = keras_cv.models.RetinaNet(
num_classes=2,
bounding_box_format="xywh",
backbone=keras_cv.models.ResNet50Backbone.from_preset(
    "resnet50_imagenet"
)
)
model.backbone.trainable = False

for layer in model.layers:
if hasattr(layer, 'rate'):
    layer.rate = 0.5


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, global_clipnorm=10.0)

# Train model
model.compile(
classification_loss='focal',
box_loss='huber',
optimizer=optimizer,
jit_compile=False
)

callbacks = [
keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=LOGS_DIR,
                            histogram_freq=1,
                            write_graph=True,
                            write_images=False,
                            update_freq='epoch',
                            profile_batch='1,2',
                            embeddings_freq=1),
keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(CHECKPOINT_PATH, save_weights_only=True)
]

print("\nTraining")

fit_history = model.fit(
train_dataset,
validation_data=valid_dataset,
epochs=EPOCHS,
callbacks=callbacks
)

print("-- history:")
print(pd.DataFrame(fit_history.history))

print(">> Done")
```

The config i am using

```
cuda-nvcc                 11.3.58              
cudatoolkit               11.2.2              
cudnn                     8.1.0.77
tensorflow            2.11
keras-cv                  0.4.2  (unreleased version, github version of the day)
```

I tried to play with learning rate, change batch size, shuffle examples, clean my data. Predictions are still the same. Also the metric percent_matched_box_with_anchor is equal at each epoch. I am expecting bounding box in pixel coordinates ( 0/512) an classes 0 or 1.    [box_loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u16Yq.png)
[classification_loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlVNg.png)
[precent_boxes_matched_with_anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrOUz.png)

Comment: Hi Hugo, Were you able to find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`-1` means no identification, so your model isn't finding anything. The reason for returning a fill value instead of nothing is so that the dimensions are always the same, so the data can be batched.

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code, but I'd check the progress in Tensorboard. Is it learning? If so, does it work correctly on the training data? Does the image you want to predict even have what you want to detect? Can you check different backbones?

If it is still not learning, you should play around with the anchor boxes and the decoder, specially important if your objects are very small or very skinny.